# UserScriptを用いて別ドメインのページに対してScriptを実行することは可能？

Tags: javascript

**hoge.com/0001.html**

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
https://rehoge.com/1234.html
</body>
</html>
```

上記ページから `rehoge.com/1234.html` に対してScriptを実行することは可能ですか？
例えば `rehoge.com/1234.html` 内で `hoge();` を実行すると特定のテキストが表示される仕様だったとして

```js
DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
```

などのScriptで `hoge.com/0001.html` 上からそのテキストを取得したいと考えます。

Answer (score 0):

クロスサイトスクリプティング相当する内容であるかと読み取れます。

セキュリティ上の理由により、ほとんどのブラウザでブロックされるかと思います。